# Highcharts Percentage area graph splined?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to make the lines in the [HighCharts Percentage area graph](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked-percent) with a [spline](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/areaspline)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? You can change the chart type to `spline`. Although that is not an `area` chart so it will look different. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the chart type from 'area' to 'areaspline' and rename the `area` property under plotOptions to `areaspline` - if that's what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/rNMmp/

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I actually did try the first step you mentioned " chart type from 'area' to 'areaspline'", but I did not know I also needed the second step "rename the area property under plotOptions to areaspline".